# Facade pattern usage with JDBC-resource on Glassfish

Tags: java, database, server, jpa, jsf

For [this project](https://github.com/THUFIR/EntAppWeb):

> ```
> NetBeansProjects/EntAppWeb/
> ├── build.xml
> ├── EntAppWeb-ejb
> │   ├── build.xml
> │   ├── nbproject
> │   │   ├── ant-deploy.xml
> │   │   ├── build-impl.xml
> │   │   ├── genfiles.properties
> │   │   ├── private
> │   │   │   ├── private.properties
> │   │   │   └── private.xml
> │   │   ├── project.properties
> │   │   └── project.xml
> │   └── src
> │       └── conf
> │           └── MANIFEST.MF
> ├── EntAppWeb-war
> │   ├── build.xml
> │   ├── nbproject
> │   │   ├── ant-deploy.xml
> │   │   ├── build-impl.xml
> │   │   ├── genfiles.properties
> │   │   ├── private
> │   │   │   ├── private.properties
> │   │   │   └── private.xml
> │   │   ├── project.properties
> │   │   └── project.xml
> │   ├── setup
> │   │   └── glassfish-resources.xml
> │   ├── src
> │   │   ├── conf
> │   │   │   ├── MANIFEST.MF
> │   │   │   └── persistence.xml
> │   │   └── java
> │   │       └── dur
> │   │           ├── beans
> │   │           │   ├── NextClient.java
> │   │           │   └── NextClientLocal.java
> │   │           └── jpa
> │   │               ├── AbstractFacade.java
> │   │               ├── ClientFacade.java
> │   │               ├── ClientFacadeLocal.java
> │   │               ├── Client.java
> │   │               └── exceptions
> │   │                   ├── IllegalOrphanException.java
> │   │                   ├── NonexistentEntityException.java
> │   │                   ├── PreexistingEntityException.java
> │   │                   └── RollbackFailureException.java
> │   └── web
> │       ├── eagle.xhtml
> │       ├── falcon.xhtml
> │       ├── index.xhtml
> │       ├── menu.xhtml
> │       ├── next.xhtml
> │       ├── parrot.xhtml
> │       ├── template.xhtml
> │       └── WEB-INF
> │           └── web.xml
> ├── LICENSE
> ├── nbproject
> │   ├── ant-deploy.xml
> │   ├── build-impl.xml
> │   ├── genfiles.properties
> │   ├── private
> │   │   ├── private.properties
> │   │   └── private.xml
> │   ├── project.properties
> │   └── project.xml
> ├── README.md
> └── src
>     └── conf
>         └── MANIFEST.MF
> ```

with this backing bean:

```java
package dur.beans;

import dur.jpa.Client;
import dur.jpa.ClientFacadeLocal;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named("nextClient")
@ApplicationScoped
public class NextClient implements NextClientLocal {

    @EJB
    private ClientFacadeLocal clientFacade;
    private int next = 1009;

    @Override
    public String getNext() {
        next++;
        Client client = clientFacade.find(next);
        return client.toString();
    }
}
```

and this facelets template client:

```html
<!DOCTYPE    html  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0  Transitional//EN"  
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      >

    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        This and everything before will be ignored
        <ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="navigation">
                <ui:include src="menu.xhtml"/>
            </ui:define>
            <ui:define name="main">
                <h1>bird</h1>
                <p>
                    next   #{nextClient.next}
                </p>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
        This and everything after will be ignored
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I want to move the `dur.jpa` package to its own project and use it as a library.  Currently the database connection is done from within the Enterprise Application with:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="EntAppWeb-warPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/legacy_resource</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I still want to use the `jdbc-resource` on glassfish.

1. Is it correct, within best practices, to use the `jdbc-resource` on glassfish?
2. How would the Java SE library utilize the `jdbc-resource` on glassfish?  How is the connection established?

See also:

- [Facade usage with JPA and Glashfish in an enterprise application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26450035/facade-usage-with-jpa-and-glassfish-in-an-enterprise-application)
- [Why use facade pattern for EJB session bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636764/why-use-facade-pattern-for-ejb-session-bean)

Answer (score 1):

There is no much code to review here, but I spotted that `next` is not `thread-safe`. You can use an [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead.

```
@EJB
private ClientFacadeLocal clientFacade;
private AtomicInteger next = new AtomicInteger(1009);

@Override
public String getNext() {
    Client client = clientFacade.find(next.incrementAndGet());
    return client.toString();
}
```

Comment: how do you know that it's not thread safe? Or, rather, how would I learn to recognize that?

Comment: @Thufir Read "Java Concurrency in Practice"